# Not able to get Login user in Django Channels using WebsocketConsumer

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, channel

---

I am not able to get login user in Django channels. I am using AuthMiddlewareStack but still facing the issue. Django channels error. Using WebsocketConsumer but not able to get current logged in user

---

```
Consumers.py


class TableData(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        print(self.scope["user"])
        self.group_name='tableData'
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()
        data = Game.get_games(1)
        
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'payload': data
        }))
```

routing.py

```
ws_pattern= [
    path('ws/tableData/',consumers.TableData),
    path('ws/room/' , consumers.Room),
    path('ws/game/room/<room_name>' , consumers.ChatConsumer)
]

application= ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        'websocket':AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(ws_pattern))
    }
)


``
```

Comment: Are you sure the user is logged in in the client?

Comment: Yes user is logged in

Comment: hi @AbhijeetGupta you make tutor for this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKYZqAVyY8A , So you already solve it ?